# Add one element at the end of every sub list of a list

Tags: list, prolog

So another prolog question here.

As the title indicated, I tried to add one element on each sublist of a list.
But things really don't go well. Here's my code so far:

```
add_char(Char, Motif, NewM):- append(Motif, [Char], NewM).
add_all(Char, [], _, RE).
add_all(Char, [H|T], Pred, RE):-
    add_char(Char, H, NewH),
    append(Pred, [NewH], RE),
    add_all(Char, T, RE, NewRE).
```

My code just wanna return the head instead of the whole list as result. like:

```
?- add_all(h, [(v=[1,2,3]), (i = [5,6,7]), (e = [r,e,w])], [],X).
X = [v=[1, 2, 3, h]]
```

What I expect is

```
X = [v=[1, 2, 3, h],i = [5,6,7,h],e = [r,e,w,h]].
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you are conveniently ignoring:

> Singleton variables: [Char,RE]
>
> Singleton variables: [NewRE]

Attend to those warnings, they are there to point out problems.

Anyway; those things in your list are not exactly sublists; you have a list of terms properly written as `=(v,[1,2,3])`, so you cannot use append on them until you take them apart ('destructure' them) and get the lists out.

```
add_char(Char, (X=Motif), (X=NewM)) :-  % destructures v=[1,2,3]
    append(Motif, [Char], NewM).        % appends to [1,2,3]


add_all(_, [], []).                     % stops when [H|T] is empty []

add_all(Char, [H|T], [NewH|Rs]):-       % relates [H|T] and [NewH|NewHs]
    add_char(Char, H, NewH),            % adds this one
    add_all(Char, T, Rs).               % does the rest
```

It is weird to use `=` like `(v=[1,2,3])` I think `v-[1,2,3]` is more standard. And SWI Prolog is optimised if you put the `[H|T]` as the first argument, because stepping over lists is so common, so swap them around if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, a simple recursive solution with `append/3`.

```
add_all(_,[],[]).
add_all(El,[(V=L)|T],[(V=L1)|T1]):-
    append(L,[El],L1),
    add_all(El,T,T1).

? add_all(h, [(v=[1,2,3]), (i = [5,6,7]), (e = [r,e,w])], X).
X = [v=[1, 2, 3, h], i=[5, 6, 7, h], e=[r, e, w, h]]
false
```

If you want to remove the `false` result, place a cut (`!`) in the body of the first rule.